# How to build Facebook app with admin settings for each unique install?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Just looking for some general info on this. What I want to do is create an app that can be installed on multiple Facebook pages. This app will need to have configurable settings for each unique install.

For example and discussion sake, lets just say this app displays and image and text. I want the admin(s) for the page to be able to change the image and the text in the app.

So I have a few questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. Can you give me a general direction in which to head in to accomplish this? I'm guessing I need to set up my own database and somehow create a table in the database each time the app is installed? I could be totally wrong here.

I appreciate any kind of help!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

### Getting Fan Page ID

From a parsed signed request (to an tab iFrame) you can get the page id - the contents would be similar to the following (output of PHP print_r):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [issued_at] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [page] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => FAN_PAGE_ID // target page id
            [liked] => 1        // is the user a fan
            [admin] =>          // is the user an admin
        )

    [user] => stdClass Object
        (
            [country] => ie
            [locale] => en_GB
            [age] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [min] => 21
                )

        )

)
```

For more information see:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

### Getting the IDs of Pages A User Admins

You can get the list of pages a user admins from:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=VALID_TOKEN
```

For more details on this see:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#page-login